Font/glyph merging and remapping in Dear ImGui
For my ImGui application I want to do the following:

Load a primary font

Load a secondary font

Add a list of selected glyphs from the secondary font to the primary font:

For each glyph I want to choose the Unicode location in the primary font (remapping...) where the glyph will be placed, so I can use it in the primary font by using that Unicode in C++ strings.

Each glyph from the secondary font needs a change of location in x- and y-direction.




I did read the ImGui font-readme, plus examples, did some simple font merging, but for the above task I hardly have a clue where to start. There is a font->AddGlyph() function, but I'm not sure how to use that for the above tasks. I hope the above is possible, any hint is appreciated.

I don't think this can be done without a thorough understanding of the code, notably ImFont, ImFontAtlas and ImFontAtlas::Build. From the sound of things you want to extend the various AddFont methods with a transposition table.

@Botje: sounds like the x- and y-relocation of a glyph is not possible with the available methods. Can the Unicode remapping (task 3a) be done with standard available functions? It would at least be a start for me...

No, that's why I mentioned adding a transposition table.

@Botje: ah, my misunderstanding, lack of knowledge in this field. Thanks though for pointing out the difficulty of this task.

I would not call it 'difficult' per se. It's a matter of sneaking in a transpositionTable[c] in the right place.

@Botje: I'm on a different way now for a solution. I wrote a Python script for FontForge to make a single fontfile with the variations I need. So far it seems to work very well and easy.
